# Jquery function add/remove class from div on button hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

I have this jquery script that I got some help with in creating in order to add/remove an "active" class to a div when hovering over a button.

Below a CodePen of what I have put together:

**CodePen Link**: https://codepen.io/dustin-keeslar/pen/dapLWM

It works well, however what I'm trying to change is to have whatever button was last hovered on, to keep the "active" class on the content. So that the content only changes when a different button is hovered over.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery(".toggle-button").hover(function() {
    var target = jQuery(this).data("target");

    if (jQuery(this).hasClass("expand")) {
      jQuery(this).toggleClass("expand");

      jQuery("#" + target).removeClass("active");
    } else {
      jQuery(".toggle-button").removeClass("expand");
      jQuery(".hidden-content").removeClass("active");

      jQuery(this).toggleClass('expand');

      jQuery("#" + target).toggleClass("active");
    }

  });
});
```

This will find a button that has `data-target=content1"` for example, and when it is hovered over it will toggle an "active" class to a div with the ID "content1". The problem is that when you are no longer hovering, everything disappears. I need the most recent hovered button to keep the "active" class on the content. But I also need the content to change dynamically when the next button is hovered over.

Comment: Are you open to a pure JavaScript approach too?

Comment: Please include all relevant code such that others can reproduce the issue here on Stack Overflow, not only on an external site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide a runnable example here on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Then fix it to use mouseenter, and move your remove code to the top to remove your classes before adding them back to the element that's been entered. I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do here, but using mouseenter it should be something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery(".toggle-button").mouseenter(function() {
  jQuery(".toggle-button").removeClass("expand");
 //      jQuery(".hidden-content").removeClass("active");
  $(".active").removeClass("active");
  var target = jQuery(this).data("target");
  jQuery("#" + target).addClass("active");

  if (jQuery(this).hasClass("expand")) {
    jQuery(this).removeClass("expand");

    jQuery("#" + target).removeClass("active");
  }

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you are missing is a check, to ensure the current item matches the target:

```
 jQuery(this).attr('id') == target
```

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VgKOPy